# htaccess redirect from url with querystring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

when I digit this url:

```
http://www.mydomain/search.php?page=1&order=ASC&contract=rent&new=
```

url should redirect to

```
http://www.mydomain/rent/1
```

I try to add this line in my .htaccess, without success:

```
Redirect http://www.mydomain/search.php?page=1&order=ASC&contract=rent&new= http://www.mydomain/rent/1
```

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines instead (but you'll only need to add the first line if it isn't there already):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)&order=ASC&contract=rent&new=$
RewriteRule search.php /rent/%1? [L,R=301]
```